# Assemble values from Map using Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream, reactive-programming

Sorry maybe for dumb question. I am looking for elegant way to go over elements of my map and filter properties.

Let's say I have map with two elements.

```
Map<String, MyElement> myMap;
```

This is how looks my element

```
class MyElement {

Map <String, Property1> properties1;
Map <String, Property2> properties2;

}
```

MyElement[0] includes **properties1** map filled with some properties, and **properties2** is null.

MyElement[1] includes **properties2** map filled with some properties, and **properties1** is null.

It might be vise versa, I have no idea for which MyElelmet Internal Maps are null and for which are not.

I would like to go over each MyElement in map and assemble properties1 or properties2 from each element in case if it is not empty.

**Result should be two separate maps** (new collections)

```
Map <String, Property1> assembledProperties1;
Map <String, Property2> assembledProperties2;
```

You can think about it as a collecting results to multiple outputs (assembledProperties1, assembledProperties2).

Is there any elegant way to do it with Java streams, without ugly if statements?

Comment: Clarify please: either of the two maps `properties1` or `properties2` inside each `MyElement ` will always be `null`?

Comment: What should be the end result? A list of maps? What would be the type of the list?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko, as mentioned I need two separate maps, one holds objects of type Property1, second - Property2. 

I can pre-create those and populate them as a reference to my method in order to fill it.

Comment: So you want to merge all the maps that are not `null`?

Comment: Yes, from each MyElement. And my going looping once.

Comment: @liotur *Is there any elegant way to do it with Java streams, without ugly if statements?* If you provided your question with the code that shows how to approach this problem with `if` statements, it would be more clear to create a stream-based solution. And also it would be helpful for the future readers with the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since don't want to utilize `MyElement` as a mutable container, you can define a special type of object that will carry references to the maps of properties.

In order to be able to perform mutable reduction on a stream of type `MyElement` with this object we need to define a method that will expect `MyElement` as a parameter to update maps based on the next element of the stream, and another method that is needed to merge partial results of execution in parallel (i.e. to combine the two objects).

```
public class PropertyWrapper {
    private Map<String, Property1> properties1 = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String, Property2> properties2 = new HashMap<>();
    
    public PropertyWrapper merge(MyElement element) {
        if (element.getProperties1() != null) properties1.putAll(element.getProperties1());
        if (element.getProperties2() != null) properties2.putAll(element.getProperties2());
        return this;
    }
        
    public PropertyWrapper merge(PropertyWrapper other) {
        this.properties1.putAll(other.getProperties1());
        this.properties2.putAll(other.getProperties2());
        return this;
    }

    // getters and toString()
}
```

With that, the actual code might look like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, MyElement> sourceMap =
        Map.of("key1", new MyElement(Map.of("a", new Property1("a"), "b", new Property1("b")), null),
               "key2", new MyElement(null, Map.of("c", new Property2("c"), "d", new Property2("d"))));

    PropertyWrapper result = sourceMap.values().stream()
        .collect(
            PropertyWrapper::new,
            PropertyWrapper::merge,
            PropertyWrapper::merge);

    System.out.println(result.getProperties1());
    System.out.println(result.getProperties2());
}
```

*Output*

```
{a=Property1{a}, b=Property1{b}}
{d=Property2{d}, c=Property2{c}}
```

Also note that it's a good practice to avoid keeping nullable references to collections. If these fields will always be initialized with empty collection, the need of null-check will be eliminated.

Comment: I can not. It is immutable object.

Comment: @liotur But these maps are still mutable even if you apply final modifier to them.

Comment: I mean I can not/ don't want to change those. Those objects are result of some prior parsing. Is there any way to collect different type of elements to different collections while going over elements?

Comment: @liotur Or you can create an auxiliary type for that purpose that will carry the references to the maps of properties. If this option seems to be more suitable for your purposes, I'll change the answer accordingly.

Comment: @liotur *Those objects are result of some prior parsing* - the initial object will not be effected, only newly created instance will be changed (just to be on the same page). Anyway, I'll edit the answer in a minute.

Comment: @liotur I've updated the answer and provided an example with dummy objects.